# how to add uniqid in image upload in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a function to insert data in a table and this data includes image/file . I think my form didn't have problem but after I added this uniqid(), it can't be submitted with error "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null"

```
 public function store_pelatihan(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        // 'title'       => 'required|min:5',
        // 'description' => 'required|min:5|max:14'
    ] );

    if($request->hasfile('file_scan'))

    {   
    $file = $request->file('file_scan');
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        $fileName = $file.'.'.uniqid().'.'.$extension; 
        $file->move(public_path().'/files/', $fileName);  
        $data = $fileName;  
    }


    $users = new Master_seminar_pelatihan;
    $users->user_id              = $request->user_id ;
    $users->nama_pelatihan       = $request->nama_pelatihan ;
    $users->nomor_pelatihan      = $request->nomor_pelatihan ;
    $users->tanggal              = $request->tanggal ;
    $users->uraian               = $request->uraian ;
    $users->tempat               = $request->tempat ;
    $users->file_scan            = $data;

    dd($data);
    // $users->save();
    // return redirect ('pelatihan')->with('success', 'Input Succes');


}
```

Previously, I was running this code and it was running without error:

```
$extension = $request->image->getClientOriginalExtension(); 

$fileName = $file.'.'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line :

```
$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension()
```

to :

```
$file->getClientOriginalExtension()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concatenating with **'.'** before **uniqid()** it'll take **extension** so either you use **'-'** or **'_'**.

```
$fileName = $file.'_'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;
```

Or

```
$fileName = $file.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Check file `isValid()` first
- Get `getClientOriginalExtension()` of the **$file** (not *$request->image*)
- Do not concatenate **$file** (it is UploadedFile) variable with strings. **$name** should be instead

```php
    if ($request->hasfile('file_scan') && $request->file('file_scan')->isValid()) {
        $file = $request->file_scan;
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = $name . '.' . uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
        $file->move(public_path() . '/files/', $fileName);
        $data = $fileName;
    }
```